# Form submitted Successfully

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, forms, validation

I'm working on a project in React and ran into a problem that has me stumped.
I want to add new user and throw alert as form added successfully. and alert when form failed with error msg.
So here is my code and I am not able to figure out how to give custom message.
If any one have some solution it will be really great if you help me

```
import { Component } from "react";
import url from "../components/ApiCall";
import FormElements from "../components/FormElements";
import FormElementStyles from "../styles/Form.module.css";
//component to add employee form
class AddEmployeeForm extends Component {
    //add new employee details from form
    submitForm = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // console.log(event.target.imageUrl.files[0]);
        let form = event.target;
        let formObj = new FormData();
        formObj.append("firstName", form.firstName.value);
        formObj.append("lastName", form.lastName.value);
        formObj.append("company", form.company.value);
        formObj.append("email", form.email.value);
        formObj.append("contact", form.contact.value);
        formObj.append("imageUrl", form.imageUrl.files[0]);
        formObj.append("skills", form.skills.value.split(","));
        formObj.append("altDescription", form.altDescription.value);
        formObj.append("hobbies", form.hobbies.value.split(","));
        formObj.append("gitHub", form.gitHub.value);
        formObj.append("linkedIn", form.linkedIn.value);
        formObj.append("website", form.website.value);

        fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",

            mode: "cors",
            body: formObj,
        })
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                alert("Form Submitted Successfully");
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                alert(err);
                alert("Failed");
            });

        form.reset();
    };
```

Comment: So you're saying that `alert("Form Submitted Successfully");` doesn't work in your code?

Comment: no if error occur then its printing in console and showing me `alert("form submitted succesfully");` not `alert("Failed"):` or `alert(err);` @Tethys0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You only wanna reset your form when the form submission is succeeded.
2. On the catch call in your promise chain, you have access to the form elements, you could simply use that to show the custom message.

```
class AddEmployeeForm extends Component {
    //add new employee details from form
    submitForm = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // console.log(event.target.imageUrl.files[0]);
        let form = event.target;
        let formObj = new FormData();
        formObj.append("firstName", form.firstName.value);
        formObj.append("lastName", form.lastName.value);
        formObj.append("company", form.company.value);
        formObj.append("email", form.email.value);
        formObj.append("contact", form.contact.value);
        formObj.append("imageUrl", form.imageUrl.files[0]);
        formObj.append("skills", form.skills.value.split(","));
        formObj.append("altDescription", form.altDescription.value);
        formObj.append("hobbies", form.hobbies.value.split(","));
        formObj.append("gitHub", form.gitHub.value);
        formObj.append("linkedIn", form.linkedIn.value);
        formObj.append("website", form.website.value);

        fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",

            mode: "cors",
            body: formObj,
        })
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                form.reset();
                alert("Form Submitted Successfully");
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                alert(err);
                // you have access to the form data here. Use it.
                // something like this, maybe
                alert(`${form.firstName.value}, Please try again`);
            });
    };
```

Comment: but m still not getting alert when there is some error

Comment: @Aakash you should be getting some error. Could you create a sandbox link so that I could what's the issue with it?